# android imageview's tint set in xml overrides tint set on DrawableCompat programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-drawable

so another day, another problem! I've set an `ImageView` with a tint, as follows:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_money"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_money_icon"
    android:tint="#c7c7c7"/>
```

And I need to revert or set the tintColor, so I used `DrawableCompat` as follows:

```
Drawable imagem = holder.view.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_money_icon);
imagem = DrawableCompat.wrap(imagem);
imagem = imagem.mutate();
DrawableCompat.setTint(imagem,Color.parseColor("#43a085"));
holder.imageDebito.setImageDrawable(imagem);
```

I inspected the bitmap on `imagem` and it looks as it should, with the color that I've set, but when applied to the ImageView `imageDebito` it reverts to the tint set on the XML. If I take a different image that isn't used in the view, apply the tint, and then set it on the ImageView, it gets the same tint from the XML... I've tried setting `setImageTintList()`, but it isn't available on API level 17...

So, I need either to remove the tint property, or enforce the tint on the image over the ImageView's one from the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setColorFilter()` method.

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button ); 
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
myIcon.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Edit: just improved the formatting...